# Find y function of cos(y) = x

Tags: trigonometry

Let's say that there is no limit to $x$, then I believe $y = \arccos(x) + \pi n $ because $\cos(y) = x$ for $x + \pi n , n\in \mathbb{Z}$. However, in the last step of [the following calculation](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/ordinary-differential-equation-calculator/y'siny%20%3D%20-%5Cfrac%7Bcosy%7D%7B1%2Be%5E%7B-x%7D%7D), it shows that the solution is $y = \arccos(x) + 2\pi n , y = -\arccos(x) + 2\pi n $:

[image]

Is this correct?

Comment: There are a couple of things in your question which I find confusing.  These may be actually errors in your thinking, but may also just be typographical.  (1) What do you mean by "there is no limit on $x$"?  (2) You say that $\cos(y) = x$ for $x + \pi n$.  I do not know how to parse this.  It is true that if $\cos(y) = x$, then $\cos(\pm y+2\pi n) = x$ for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Your first sentence should presumably end with "for $y+\pi n$", since the periodicity applies to $\cos$ and not $\text{arccos}$.(Also, the Latex code for the integers is `\mathbb{Z}`: $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: "I believe $y = \arccos(x) + \pi n $ because $\cos(y) = x$ for $x + \pi n , n\in \mathbb{Z}$" That's not true.  $\cos (x+(2n+1)\pi)= -\cos x$.

Comment: Thank you... As a fourth year math student, I somehow confused that $\cos(x)$ for $x$ in third quadrant is positive..... Shame on me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take as example $x=1/2$. Then your formula would give the solutions of $\cos y=1/2$ as $y=\text{arccos}(1/2)+\pi n=\pi/3+\pi n$, which in particular would include $y=4\pi/3$ for $n=1$. But $\cos(4\pi/3)=-\cos(\pi/3)=-1/2$, so this is not a solution and your proposed solution set cannot be correct.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your question is.  $\cos$ is not injective (it's possible for two different values to have the same output) so there in no inverse function, $f$ where $f(x)= y$ whenever $\cos y = x$.

If your question is to *solve* all possible $y$ where $\cos y = x$.

We have if $0\le \arccos y \le \pi$ is the only solution between $0$ and $\pi$.

Likewise for any $k\in \mathbb Z$ we have $\arccos y + 2k\pi$ is the only solution between $2k\pi$ and $(2k+1)\pi$.

But what about the solutions between $(2k+1)\pi$ and $(2k+2)\pi$?  Or equivalently between $(2k-1)\pi$ and $2k\pi$?

bearing in mind that $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$ we have $-\pi \le -\arccos y \le 0$ is the only solution between $-\pi$ and $0$ and so $-\arccos y + (2k-1)\pi$ is the only solution between $(2k-1)\pi$ and $2k\pi$.

And thus the solutions will by all the $y$ where $y = \arccos x + 2k\pi$ or $y = -\arccos x + (2k-1)\pi$ for some $k$.

> because cos(y)=x for x+πn,n∈Z

That isn't true. if $n$ is an odd number then $\cos(x + \pi n) = -\cos x \ne \cos x$